# Не записываются данные в модель

Tags: php, yii2

Пост, который приходит:

```
[
'UserInfo' => [
    'name' => 'ewewe'
    'surname' => 'ewewew'
    'dateBirth' => '1229-12-12'
    'sex' => 'man'
    ]
]
```

Модель, данные должны записываться в [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes]:

```
app\models\db\UserInfo#1
(
[yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => []
[yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_oldAttributes] => null
[yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_related] => []
[yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_relationsDependencies] => []
[yii\base\Model:_errors] => null
[yii\base\Model:_validators] => ArrayObject#2
(
```

Тут возвращает true:

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '');
```

Знаю, что проблема  с неймами, передаю вот таким скриптом:

```
$scope.userRegSecondForm = function(){ 
        var secForm = {
            name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            surname: $('input[name="surname"]').val(),
            dateBirth: $('input[name="dateBirth"]').val(),
            sex: $('select[name="sex"] option[selected]').val(),
            };
        var userSecondFormData = {
            UserInfo : secForm
        };
        console.log(userSecondFormData);
        return userSecondFormData;
    }
```

Comment: Валидацию указали для атрибутов ?

Comment: Я делаю load еще до валидации, и соответственно записываться в должно тоже раньше. + rules в модели я временно закомментировал

Comment: При такой загрузке: $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), '');
нужно указать rules. Cделайте как-то так и все заработает: 

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'surname', 'dateBirth', 'sex',], 'string'],
        ];
    }

Comment: rules добавил, на вский случай, не пишет ничего. Насколько я знаю, они нужны для $model->validate(), но у меня с этим все нормально

Comment: Через метод load будут загружаться только те атрибуты которые есть у rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы передаете в модель данные, с явным указанием, что нужные данные  содержатся в корне _POST, а не во вложенном массиве

```
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), ''); 
// 2ой аргумент load пустая строка, что говорит модели "Не ищи данные в массиве "UserInfo"
```

Однако Вы все равно отправляете данные в массиве UserInfo, разумеется модель его и не видит.

Чтобы работал конкретно Ваш код - либо уберите 2ой аргумент в load

```
$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

Либо не добавляйте данные при отправке в массив `UserInfo`

```
$scope.userRegSecondForm = function(){ 
        var secForm = {
            name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            surname: $('input[name="surname"]').val(),
            dateBirth: $('input[name="dateBirth"]').val(),
            sex: $('select[name="sex"] option[selected]').val(),
            };
        console.log(secForm);
        return secForm;
    }
```

Comment: Дело в том, что вчера я сделал это первым делом(убрал 2й аргумент в load), но тогда результат мне возвращал false, сейчас. перед тем как вам ответить, еще раз попробывал, и заработало, load вернул true и атрибуты записались. Странно конечно, но все работает, спасибо.